# When pointers are used in a struct field, where is the underlying value actually stored?

Tags: string, go, pointers, struct, field

For an example, let's take this struct

```
var input struct {
Title *string `json:"title"`
Year *int32 `json:"year"`
Runtime *data.Runtime `json:"runtime"`
Genres []string `json:"genres"`
}
```

I get the purpose of using pointer values like this when decoding JSON values. But my question is when we store a pointer to a string in the input field (for an ex) `input.Title`, Where does the underlying value for that pointer is stored? It's simply stored in some memory address randomly? or what actually is going on behind the scenes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack vs heap allocation of structs in Go, and how they relate to garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866195/stack-vs-heap-allocation-of-structs-in-go-and-how-they-relate-to-garbage-collec)

Comment: „In memory“. That’s all to know here. Neither the language specification nor encoding/json make any guaranties except the the data _is_ stored.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I guess it's a bit different concept. It was very informative ty. But I think memcpy's answer makes a lot of sense to my question. I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON decoder calls [reflect.New](https://godoc.org/reflect#New) to get a pointer to a new empty string value. The decoder sets the value to the decoded string and [sets](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Set) the struct field to the pointer.

The reflect.New function calls a private runtime function to allocate heap memory for the value. The function returns a pointer to that memory.

Comment: "The reflect.New function calls a private runtime function to allocate memory" Is this allocated memory temporary? like it's a stack level thing or heap level thing?

Comment: It's a heap thing, but that distinction is not important unless you are optimizing allocations.  The important thing is that the memory allocation has a lifetime equal to or greater than any references to the memory.